# Triggering an action from a store or accessing a store inside an action

Tags: reactjs, refluxjs

I am building a test application using reactjs and refluxjs where I show a list of images from an API with pagination.

Currently I have one **PicturesStore** and two actions: **RefreshAction** and **PageChangeAction**.

The filters for filtering the images that I fetch from the server are in the **PicturesStore**.

The **RefreshAction** is emitted to fetch new images from the server based on the filters that live in **PicturesStore**.

The **PageChangeAction** is emitted to refresh the filter (by changing the page number) and then emit the **RefreshAction** to refresh the pictures.

I am a bit lost on how to proceed here. I can think of two approaches to change the current page number and fetch the images from the server based on this page number and the filters that live inside **PicturesStore**, but I don't know which one could be the best or if there's a better one.

**1st approach**: emit the **PageChangeAction** in the react component and update the page number inside the PicturesStore. Once updated, emit the RefreshAction from the **PicturesStore** (**call an action inside a store**).

**2nd approach**: emit the **PageChangeAction**, update the page number inside the **PicturesStore**, use **CathegoryChangeAction.changePage.listen** method to trigger the **RefreshAction** (**emitting an action inside of another action**), but the problem is that inside **RefreshAction** I need to access the filters that live inside **PicturesStore** (**accessing a store inside an action**).

Please let me know if I've been clear enough.

Comment: I would definately go for the 1st approach. This keeps. the code lines mostly in one file (store) and therefore easier to read. You also do not need to create special constructs to access the filter in the store.

Comment: Indeed. This is the approach that I am currently using, but I still would like to see if there's a better way.

Comment: You can only check if there is a better way if you are able to define the drawbacks on your selected approach. Why do you think that the 1st approach is not good enough? We've found out that when using React and Reflux, you can't always work as suggested in the documentation, but if you and your team pick a way of working and stick to that, it will probably work out quite well!